# Apps run in bottles typing delay and changing icon size in app

Tags: 20.04

When i installed an editor app in bottle, i noticed there a delay while i typing, text that i typed show at the bottom left corner of the app but not in the editor (like in the picture when i run notpad++), util i press space or enter the text show up in the editor. How can i fix it? And how can i change the size of the icon button in the editor?

thanks,
[image]
[image]